# Error 500 while archiva setup on local

Tags: maven, archiva

I am trying to setup Archiva on windows machine. Below is the error i get while trying to create a admin user.

Problem accessing /archiva/security/register.action. Reason:

```
Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
```

nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Caused by:

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:342)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:338)
    at org.codehaus.redback.integration.mail.MailerImpl.sendMessage(MailerImpl.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.redback.integration.mail.MailerImpl.sendAccountValidationEmail(MailerImpl.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.redback.struts2.action.RegisterAction.register(RegisterAction.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:404)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:88)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)

Did anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution - define smtp server:

In jetty.xml:

```
 <Resource name="mail/Session"  type="javax.mail.Session" auth="Container" 
   mail.smtp.host="localhost" 
   mail.smtp.auth="true" 
   mail.user="USERNAME" 
   mail.password="PASSWORD" 
   mail.port="25" 
   mail.transport.protocol="smtp" 
   mail.debug="true"/>
```

Or install smtp server on windows. Now I do not know if you can disable mail configuration.